# USB modalias. Meaning of numeric values

Tags: linux, usb, sysfs

For the USB modaliases, I know that the values corresponding to the device's vendor and product ids can be found here: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

Which online resources and/or kernel source files, I could use to find the meaning for the rest of the ids: d, dc, dsc, dp, ic, isc, ip, in?

For example, I've got this modalias:

```
usb:v0525pA4A5d0001dc02dsc00dp00ic02isc02ip01in00
```

Finding the meaning of vendor id (0525) and product id (a4a5) is easy using aforementioned web-page. But I have no idea where to look up the rest of the ids.

Update: I understand what the letters mean (v, p, d, dc, etc). But the numeric values are in question.

Update2: Take [this article](http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html) for example. Among other things the author says that "The 0900 device class/subclass means hub" and that "Interface class 0E01 is video control". But where does this knowledge come from?

In my case:
device class/subclass (dc:dsc) is 0200.
interface class/subclass (ic:isc) is 0202.

What does these numbers mean? Where to lookup them?

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer myself. It appears that http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids also contains the meaning for the device/interface classes, subclasses and protocols. They are almost at the end of the file. Search it for "List of known device classes, subclasses and protocols" string.

So in my case: ic:isc:ip (which is 02:02:01) means a communication device, a modem with AT-commands (v.25ter).

Which is not exactly true. It is a development board connected to my PC. So it is a serial (uart?) port. But it is a different story...